# Saving state in spring bean using ThreadLocal

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two services ( A and B) that i communicate with using Command pattern

Command:

```
public interface Command {
    void execute() throws CommandExecutionException;
    void rollback() throws CommandExecutionException;
    String commandName();
}
```

My use case is

1. communicate with service A using commands
2. if error occurs in any command communicating with service A, rollback all previously executed commands for A
3. communicate with service B using commands
4. if error occurs in any command communicating with service B, rollback all previously executed commands for B, and all commands for A ( since all were previously executed if we get to this point )

Now i am doing it this way:

```
@Service
public class A{
    // some autowired dependencies
    private final ThreadLocal<List<Command>> executedCommandsByThread = new ThreadLocal<>();

       @Override
    public void executeServiceA() throws ServiceAException{
        // create commands
        Command command1 = new CommandA1(...);
        Command command2 = new CommandA2(...);
        Command command3 = new CommandA3(...);

        List<Command> commandList = new LinkedList<>();
        // add them to linked list
        commandList.add(command1 );
        commandList.add(command2 );
        commandList.add(command3 );

        RollBackCommandManager commandManager = new RollBackCommandManager(commandList);

        try {
            //execute
            commandManager.execute();
            executedCommandsByThread.set(commandList);
        } catch (CommandManagerException e) {
            LOGGER.info("Service A failed");
            throw new ServiceAException("Service A failed", e);
        }
    }

    public void rollback() {
        List<Command> commandList = executedCommandsByThread.get();
        CommandManager commandManager = new RollBackCommandManager(commandList);
        try {
            commandManager.rollback();
            executedCommandsByThread.remove();
        } catch (CommandManagerException e) {
            throw new ServiceAException("Service A rollback failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

and B

```
@Service
public class B{
    // some autowired dependencies
    private final ThreadLocal<List<Command>> executedCommandsByThread = new ThreadLocal<>();

       @Override
    public void executeServiceB() throws ServiceBException{
        // create commands
        Command command1 = new CommandB1(...);
        Command command2 = new CommandB2(...);
        Command command3 = new CommandB3(...);

        List<Command> commandList = new LinkedList<>();
        // add them to linked list
        commandList.add(command1 );
        commandList.add(command2 );
        commandList.add(command3 );

        RollBackCommandManager commandManager = new RollBackCommandManager(commandList);

        try {
            //execute
            commandManager.execute();
            executedCommandsByThread.set(commandList);
        } catch (CommandManagerException e) {
            LOGGER.info("Service B");
            throw new ServiceBException("Service B failed", e);
        }
    }

    public void rollback() {
        List<Command> commandList = executedCommandsByThread.get();
        CommandManager commandManager = new RollBackCommandManager(commandList);
        try {
            commandManager.rollback();
            executedCommandsByThread.remove();
        } catch (CommandManagerException e) {
            throw new ServiceBException("Service B rollback failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

`CommandManager` handles execution of commands, and if error occurs it rollbacks all previously executed commands.

I am working with these services using Facade:

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
class Facade {
  private final ServiceA serviceA;
  private final ServiceB serviceB;

  public void communicate(){
     try{
        serviceA.executeServiceA();
        serviceB.executeServiceB();
     }catch( ServiceAException e ) {
        throw new FacadeException();
     }catch( ServiceBException e ){
       // error occured while executing commands for B. Command manager in ServiceB handles rollback of commands for B, but we need to rollback commands for A too;
       serviceA.rollback();
     }
  }
}
```

As explained in the comment. When exception in `ServiceB` occurs, the commands for `ServiceB` are rollbacked by `CommandManager` in `ServiceB`. But i need to rollback commands executed in `ServiceA` too - and for that reason i need to remember what commands were executed. I am using `Threadlocal` for this, but the `ServiceA` is Spring bean - and i am not sure this way of "saving state in spring bean" is ok. This code is part of back end and will be communicating with other services/front end using Rest-API - application server will call this separate thread for each request, thus `ThreadLocal` solution should in theory be safe. However, isnt there better way of doing this?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I would caution against using ThreadLocal for this sort of thing. You create a dependence on the fact that certain actions are executed in the same Thread. That assumpion may hold now, but what if another unsuspecting developer changes te implementation, making it multithreaded in some way? That may not be very likely in this case, but in general I would consider using ThreadLocal in this way a bad practice.

I see some alternatives. If A and B are always used in the context of an HTTP request, you could consider using request scoped beans. In this case a new instance of your bean is created for each API request. Here is a blog about bean scopes: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes

The second option is to just have Service A return the list of executed commands, and have the rollback() method of Service a accept a list of commands to be rolled back.

Your code is probably a simplification, but if I read it correctly you have a single class RollbackCommandManager that can execute or rollback commands from either A or B. So the only things that actually make A and B unique is the fact that they define different commands. I would be inclined to do something like this, which has the added advantage of making it easy to add more services like A and B.

```
public abstract class CommandServiceBase{



    public void execute(List<Command> executedCommandsContext) {
        List<Command> commands = getCommands();

        RollBackCommandManager commandManager = new RollBackCommandManager(commandList);

        try {
            //execute
            commandManager.execute();
            executedCommandsContext.addAll(commandList);
        } catch (CommandManagerException e) {
            RollBackCommandManager commandManager = new RollBackCommandManager(executedCommandsContext);
            commandManager.rollback()
            throw new CommandServiceException("Service has failed", e);
        }
    }

    private abstract void getCommands();
}
```

And then just have A and B extend CommandServiceBase, and implement getCommands();